# What Code Forces Widescreen in Youtube?

Tags: css, code, userscripts, stylish

What code do I use to force widescreen and 360p on Youtube? I'm using the following style in Stylish:

https://userstyles.org/styles/101312/dark-youtube-light-blue

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with *Stylish* on YouTube; you need a userscript or extension, because it is a matter of javascript/page state, not (just) CSS.

There's several extensions out there already. I use [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki) -- which is available as a userscript and/or an extension on most major browsers.